# Weird error page after YSOD ASP.NET with Visual Studio built-in debugging server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ysod

Now that I am playing with NHibernate I am getting a lot more YSODs as I am learning it however I seem to get this error sometimesafter a YSOD:

This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://localhost:49497/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 139 (net::ERR_TEMPORARILY_THROTTLED): Unknown error.

Is there any way to disable this because I have to wait a few minutes every time and that is a pretty big killer is productivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Google Chrome, because a search on the error message shows that it's a ["feature"](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=66062) of Chrome.  If a page returns a 500 error too many times Chrome will "throttle" access to the page, apparently is some sort of anti DDOS mechanism in Chrome.

I've never seen it personally, but the commenters on the thread I linked said it looked like it was coming from the server.